# Snowflake with On-premise

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've started learning Snowflake and have few questions about its functionality.

My company requires to extract/source data from Oracle & SQL Server databases, which are in their on-premise. Now while going through functionalities of Snowflake, I found that it can consume data only from cloud provider selected (i.e. AWS/Azure/GCP). Does this mean, we will first have to move our data from on-premise to one of the cloud provider and then only we can use Snowflake for processing?

One of the thread in discussion suggested that we first load data in file, then move it to Amazon S3 bucket and then get it consumed by Snowflake.

Can someone let me know about this or any tutorial to get my doubts clear?

Comment: You are correct in how to get data into Snowflake.  There are a lot of tools that can help you with that, though, to simplify the process (ELT tools, data replication tools, etc.) which all do the same mechanics that you are describing, but they are under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike Walton already mentioned, you can load data from your on-premises DB to Snowflake with any ETL tool. This is very typical scenario using Snowflake. No need to upload fist to any other cloud service.

Snowflake provides ODBC drivers so you can access the database from your workstation or integration server just like any other DB. Further reading in here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-download.html